# loop threw an array of arrays in recursion (algorithm problem)

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array

I kinda want to create a feature which is most often known in factories. Kind of rotation system, where people swap their station, while others are on break.

via DragnDrop I create/add/update a Map and convert this map to an array of arrays like this:

```
let example1 = [
    ['John',    ['99', '1']],
    ['Jo',      ["1", "3"]],
    ["Alpha",   ["99", "4"]],
    ["Beta",    ["3", "2"]],
    ["Gamma",   ["2", "99"]],
    ["Delta",   ["4", "5"]],
    ["Maria",   ["5", "6"]],
    ["Epsilon", ["6", "99"]],
];
```

the first number is for the ***old*** Position, the second number is for the ***new*** position.
The number 99 stands for beeing on break.
the output for above example should be something like:

```
outputExample1 = [
    ["John", "1", "3", "2"], 
    ["Alpha", "4, "5", "6"] 
]
```

so every sequenze and recursion should start with a **breaker** (=number 99) and end with a breaker.
in above example: after placing "john" at station one, it should "search" where the guy/ladie from station 1 is "now". in this example, he is on 3. now search again where the one from statin 3 is now. (=2) ... until the number is 99, which is the case at this example.
thats why I started to filter the original array in 'activ'(<99) and 'breakers'(==99).
I tried so many ways and fail continously ( while loops ends in an endless loop, outputs which are totally wrong), because i dont find a nice recursion.

Any hints are very preciated

PS: please consider that above array is "finished" to provide a good example and may not be completed ***on the fly*** (via drag and drop). Meaning: if I start to drag the sequenze is for sure not  completed.

Edit: there will be for sure at least ONE '99'. if not no sequenze and no output.
Also there are no duplicates on the 'new position' except 99er. (which are the starters anyway

Comment: "*I tried so many ways and fail continously*" - please [edit] your question to include them so that we can tell what went wrong

Comment: What is the significance of the keys in the map?

Comment: @Bergi: what you mean by edit your question. I didn´t provide any snippets because all my loops (either forEach, while, ....) end  up miserable. ;-)

Comment: You say the sequences might not be complete, if you call the function while the user still drags'n'drops. What exactly are the restrictions on input that you can guarantee? Does every circle contain at least one `99`? Are the sequences allowed to diverge, i.e. can there be duplicates in the positions? What is the expected output in these cases?

Comment: @Bergi my thought was/is using a Map with the name as key (which is unique) i can drag and drop easily and update the map "easily" . Therfore the "old" and "new" position gets stroed as values in an array .

Comment: You can [edit] your question by clicking that link. [Editing is encouraged to improve posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Even if your attempts were miserable, we need to see the code to be able to help you with it. Otherwise we'd just write a solution for you, but not actually help your understanding.

Comment: @Bergi thank you Bergi. I am not used to ask for solutions, hints. I will provide some extra infos. ... and yes there will be for sure at least 1 "99", otherwise the feature doesnt make sence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a sequential approach and visit all nodes in the order, you have. Then take a nested property for the most top items and keep the relation with the nodes. At the end return just top nodes.

If necessary take the entries of the result for an array of key/value pairs.

```js
const
    data = [['John',    ['99', '1']], ['Jo',      ["1", "3"]], ["Alpha",   ["99", "4"]], ["Beta",    ["3", "2"]], ["Gamma",   ["2", "99"]], ["Delta",   ["4", "5"]], ["Maria",   ["5", "6"]], ["Epsilon", ["6", "99"]]],
    relations = data
        .reduce((r, [top, [from, to]]) => {
            if (to === '99') return r;
            if (from === '99') {
                r[to] = r.top[top] = [to];
            } else {
                r[from].push(to);
                r[to] = r[from];
            }
            return r;
        }, { top: {} })
        .top;

console.log(relations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Version without `reduce`.

```js
const
    data = [['John',    ['99', '1']], ['Jo',      ["1", "3"]], ["Alpha",   ["99", "4"]], ["Beta",    ["3", "2"]], ["Gamma",   ["2", "99"]], ["Delta",   ["4", "5"]], ["Maria",   ["5", "6"]], ["Epsilon", ["6", "99"]]],
    temp = {},
    relations = {};

for (const [top, [from, to]] of data) {
    if (to === '99') continue;
    if (from === '99') {
        temp[to] = relations[top] = [to];
    } else {
        temp[from].push(to);
        temp[to] = temp[from];
    }
}

console.log(relations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Jesus Christ. This is extra ordinary. In the beginning (and still a bit) I had no idea why on earth the reduce-method should work. Tank you miss Nina-Scholz.  it works absolutely fine. (except the fact that i have to start dragging with the 'breakers', otherwise the code breaks, but this is my 'fault' due to less information provided.) thank you again. sending 'coffee' to Düsseldorf ;)

Comment: @BlockWest Tbh imo this would be much cleaner without `.reduce`.

Comment: Note that this is sensitive to the order of the elements in the initial array.  If they were shuffled, this would usually fail.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Nina is fine, so long as your data is always sorted as in the example.  If not, then this might help:

```js
const cycleUntil = (schedule, x, [_, [f, t]] = schedule .find (([_, [f]]) => x == f)) => 
  f == 99 ? [] : [f, ... cycleUntil (schedule, t)]

const transform = (schedule) => 
  schedule .filter (([n, [f]]) => f == '99') 
           .map (([n, [f, t]]) => [n, ... cycleUntil (schedule, t)])

const example1 = [['John', ['99', '1']], ['Jo', ["1", "3"]], ["Alpha", ["99", "4"]], ["Beta", ["3", "2"]], ["Gamma", ["2", "99"]], ["Delta", ["4", "5"]], ["Maria", ["5", "6"]], ["Epsilon", ["6", "99"]] ]
console .log (transform (example1))

const example2 = [...example1, ["Zeta", ["99", "7"]], ["Eta", ["7", "10"]], ["Theta", ["8", "99"]], ["Iota", ["9", "8"]], ["Kappa", ["10", "9"]]]
console .log (transform (example2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here our `transform` function finds all elements that start with `'99'` and returns the name associated with them alongside the result of calling the `cycleUntil` function, which takes a station and the entire schedule and returns an array including that station, and, recursively, the element with that `to` station in its `from` position.

This will fail if the data is not constructed properly.  It would almost certainly need some error-checking to ensure that the data is complete.  But I'll leave that as an exercise.